# How can I start nfs-common service in chroot environment?

Tags: debian, nfs, daemon, start-stop-daemon

I'm trying to start NFS client daemon on my Debian 9.3 machine, but it doesn't start with the following message.

```
$ sudo service nfs-common start
[FAIL] Starting NFS common utilities: statd failed!
```

I tried to debug it by running it with `bash -x`, but I can't find the reason. Please help me!

```
$ sudo bash -ex /etc/init.d/nfs-common start
[...]
+ /usr/sbin/rpcinfo -p
+ RET=0
+ '[' 0 '!=' 0 ']'
+ start-stop-daemon --start --oknodo --quiet --pidfile /run/rpc.statd.pid --exec /sbin/rpc.statd --
```

`df -h | grep run` doesn't return anything, but `df` returns file systems as follows. (Debian is installed in a chroot container.)

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata   25G  6.0G   19G  25% /
tmpfs                                            927M  128K  927M   1% /dev
tmpfs                                            927M     0  927M   0% /dev/shm

$ sudo systemctl status nfs-common.service
Running in chroot, ignoring request.
```

This is the output of `ls -la /run`.

```
$ ls -la /run
total 84
drwxr-xr-x. 12 root  root    4096 Feb  4 03:05 .
drwxr-xr-x. 20 root  root    4096 Dec 29 23:52 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root    4096 Jan 28 22:38 apache2
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root       6 Feb  4 00:59 crond.pid
----------.  1 root  root       0 Jan  1 04:09 crond.reboot
drwxrwxrwt.  3 root  root    4096 Jan  1 15:59 lock
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root      87 Feb  4 02:18 motd.dynamic
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root    4096 Jan 28 05:46 mount
drwxr-xr-x.  2 mysql root    4096 Jan 28 22:38 mysqld
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  netdev  4096 Jan 28 22:36 network
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root    4096 Dec 30 22:54 proftpd
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root    6440 Dec 30 22:54 proftpd.delay
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root      16 Dec 30 22:57 proftpd.scoreboard
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root       0 Dec 30 22:57 proftpd.scoreboard.lck
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root       0 Jan 28 23:11 rpc.statd.lock
-rw-r--r--.  1 statd nogroup    0 Feb  4 03:05 rpc.statd.pid
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root    4096 Feb  4 02:47 rpcbind
-r--r--r--.  1 root  root       0 Feb  4 02:47 rpcbind.lock
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root       4 Feb  4 02:47 rpcbind.pid
srw-rw-rw-.  1 root  root       0 Feb  4 02:47 rpcbind.sock
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root    4096 Feb  4 02:47 sendsigs.omit.d
-rw-------.  1 root  root       6 Jan 28 20:03 sm-notify.pid
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root    4096 Dec 29 23:55 sshd
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root       6 Jan 28 22:28 sshd.pid
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root  utmp    2304 Feb  4 02:18 utmp
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root  root    4096 Dec 31 20:04 vsftpd
-rw-------.  1 root  root       0 Dec 30 23:11 xtables.lock
```

I think `nfs-common` service doesn't start properly if `rpcbind` is not running.

```
$ sudo rm /run/rpc.statd*
$ sudo service nfs-common start
[....] Starting NFS common utilities: statd
[warn] Not starting: portmapper is not running ... (warning).
$ sudo service nfs-common status
rpc.statd not running
```

Comment: `service rpcbind start` before starting statd/nfs  ; if need be do the rm again.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro It still fails with the same message. `[FAIL] Starting NFS common utilities: statd failed!`

Comment: sudo service rpcbind start ; sudo rm /run/rpc.statd* ; sudo service nfs-common start

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro It doesn't work either. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I will leave here the relevant bits of debugging, maybe they will help others pickup were I am leaving.